# If function on a for loop

Tags: r

I have two dataframes with different number of lines and columns, such as:

**a** (12981 lines and 3 columns)

```
Year Month Day    
1980  1     1     
1980  1     2   
1980  1     3    
1980  1     4    
1980  1     5    
...    
1980  1     31    
1980  2     1    
1980  2     2    
1980  2     3    
1980  2     4    
1980  2     5
...
```

**b** (426 lines and 3 columns)

```
Year Month Value    
1980    1   356    
1980    2   389    
1980    3   378    
1980    4   450    
1980    5   500    
...        
1981    2   450
```

I want to add "Value" column (from **b** ) to **a** to get something like this:

**a_withValues** (12981 lines with 4 columns)

```
Year Month Day Value    
1980  1     1   356    
1980  1     2   356    
1980  1     3   356    
1980  1     4   356    
1980  1     5   356    
...    
1980  1     31  356    
1980  2     1   389    
1980  2     2   389    
1980  2     3   389    
1980  2     4   389    
1980  2     5   389    
...
```

In other words if `a$Year` and `a$Month` are equal to `b$Year` and `b$Month` I want to add (for a new column in **a**) the corresponding value from `b$Value`.

Comment: Please edit your expected output. Also, a dput of your data would be nice

Comment: Use dplyr. `result <- dplyr::full_join(dataframe1, dataframe2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is a `join` of the data.frames (at least to my understanding). That includes matching `keys` of the two items and then adding the values as another column.

You can achieve merging the two datasets like this, using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- data.table(Year = 1980,
                  Month = 1:3,
                  Day = 1)
dt1
# Year Month Day
# 1: 1980     1   1
# 2: 1980     2   1
# 3: 1980     3   1

dt2 <- data.table(Year = 1980,
                  Month = 1:3,
                  Value = runif(3, 100, 1000))
dt2
# Year Month    Value
# 1: 1980     1 389.7436
# 2: 1980     2 902.0029
# 3: 1980     3 663.6313

merge(dt1, dt2, by = c("Year", "Month"), all.x = T)[order(Year, Month)]
# Year Month Day    Value
# 1: 1980     1   1 389.7436
# 2: 1980     2   1 902.0029
# 3: 1980     3   1 663.6313
```

If you just want to create another column in one data.table (note, `data.table`s are similar to a `data.frame`s in many aspects) without any matching, you can do it like this:

```
dt1$Value <- dt2$Value
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I edit my question. I hope that you can understand better know. Thank you very much!

Comment: I edited the code that it fits your question. The `all.x = T` statement is the solution. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes I' ve tried. The values were added as I wanted. Thanks fot that! Although the order odf the column "Day" appears (on the result) in a different order. For example on dataframe "a" the column "Day" is like:1, 2,3, 4, 5, 6, 7,8,9,10,11... and now appears like: "2, 1, 6, 3"

Comment: Just wrap the result in `order(Day)`. If the answer was helpful, please consider voting it up and marking it as the answer.

Comment: I do that although I don't get what I need...I want that columns "Year" "Month" and "Day" stay on the result dataframe...at an identical order then those presented on dataframe "a"...I am not sure if you could understand me...Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check again, it should be ordered now! I included the command `[order(Year, Month)]` that orders the data.table by year and then month.

Comment: Furthermore, the `all.x = T` makes sure that all entries in `x` (the first data.table to be supplied to the `merge`-function) are used and filled with matching values of `y`. This is also known as a left join.

Comment: I tried and I get this error: Error in order(Year, ) : object 'Year' not found

Comment: Make sure that you have the structure as a `data.table` and that you have a variable named `Year`. Alternatively you need to order the `data.frame` using the slower `data.frame`-solution: i.e., `mdf <- merge(dt1, dt2, by = c("Year", "Month"), all.x = T)` and then `mdf[order(mdf$Year, mdf$Month), ]`

Comment: Now I get what I want but I needed to change for:mdf[order(mdf$Year, mdf$Month, mdf$Day), ] If you could change the answer accordingly I will choose the answer as the correct .Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Good to hear. However, this includes that you work with a data.frame not a data.table (which works but is slower). Depending on your work and the size of your data.frames you might want to switch to data.table.

Answer (score 1):

There is a base R solution to this, just use the function `merge`.  By default it will choose columns with matching names, so in your case it will work out of the box

```
a <- expand.grid(year=1980, month=1:2, day=1:30)
b <- data.frame(year=1980, month=1:2, value=c(356,389))

a_with_b <- merge(a,b)
```

Here:

```
> head(a)
  year month day
1 1980     1   1
2 1980     2   1
3 1980     1   2
4 1980     2   2
5 1980     1   3
6 1980     2   3
> head(b)
  year month value
1 1980     1   356
2 1980     2   389
> head(a_with_b)
  year month day value
1 1980     1   1   356
2 1980     1   8   356
3 1980     1   2   356
4 1980     1   9   356
5 1980     1   3   356
6 1980     1  10   356
```