# Filling a column in a dataframe based on a column in another dataframe in r

Tags: r, data-analysis

I have a dataframe of comments which looks like this(df1)

```
Comments
Apple laptops are really good for work,we should buy them
Apple Iphones are too costly,we can resort to some other brands
Google search is the best search engine 
Android phones are great these days
I lost my visa card today
```

I have another dataframe of merchent names which looks like this(df2):

```
Merchant_Name
Google
Android
Geoni
Visa
Apple
MC
WallMart
```

If a merchant_name in df2 appears in a Comment in df 1 ,append that merchant name to the second column in df1 in R.The match need not be an exact match.An approximation is what is required.Also,the df1 contains around 500K rows!
My final ooutput df may look like this

```
Comments                                                        Merchant
Apple laptops are really good for work,we should buy them       Apple
Apple Iphones are too costly,we can resort to some other brands Apple
Google search is the best search engine                         Google
Android phones are great these days                             Android
I lost my visa card today                                       Visa
```

How may i do this and  efficiently in R.??
Thanks

Comment: Although the title of the other question is a bit misleading, it actually answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33672082/if-function-on-a-for-loop/33672374
What you are looking for is called a `join` or `merge` of two datasets.

Comment: @David I don't believe this is a merge at all.

Comment: @Tim, I must have skipped part of the questions, my apologies.

Comment: At a quick glance, it looks like a merge.  But remember, a merge is akin to a database join, and in this case there is no join column.  Instead, the correct answer below is extracting out the company name and creating a new column based on that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a job for `regex`. Check out the `grepl` command inside the `lapply`.

```
comments = c(
   'Apple laptops are really good for work,we should buy them',
   'Apple Iphones are too costly,we can resort to some other brands',
   'Google search is the best search engine ',
   'Android phones are great these days',
   'I lost my visa card today'
)

brands = c(
   'Google',
   'Android',
   'Geoni',
   'Visa',
   'Apple',
   'MC',
   'WallMart'
)

brandinpattern = lapply(
   brands,
   function(brand) {
      commentswithbrand = grepl(x = tolower(comments), pattern = tolower(brand))
      if ( sum(commentswithbrand) > 0) {
         data.frame(
            comment = comments[commentswithbrand],
            brand = brand
         )
      } else {
         data.frame()
      }
   }
)

brandinpattern = do.call(rbind, brandinpattern)


> do.call(rbind, brandinpattern)
                                                          comment   brand
1                        Google search is the best search engine   Google
2                             Android phones are great these days Android
3                                       I lost my visa card today    Visa
4       Apple laptops are really good for work,we should buy them   Apple
5 Apple Iphones are too costly,we can resort to some other brands   Apple
```

Comment: What if the first comment were "Google searches better than Android"?

Comment: @Codoremifa Thanks a lot for the help .. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
final_df <- data.frame(Comments = character(), Merchant_Name = character(), stringsAsFactors = F)

for(i in df1$Comments){
    for(j in df2$Merchant_Name){ 
        if(grepl(tolower(j),tolower(i))){ 
            final_df[nrow(final_df) + 1,] <- c(i, j)
            break
        }
    }
}


final_df

##                                                        comments  brands
##1       Apple laptops are really good for work,we should buy them   Apple
##2 Apple Iphones are too costly,we can resort to some other brands   Apple
##3                        Google search is the best search engine   Google
##4                             Android phones are great these days Android
##5                                       I lost my visa card today    Visa
```