# R: find value in a dataframe based on value in another dataframe

Tags: r

This question is similar to what was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33688413/filling-a-column-in-a-dataframe-based-on-a-column-in-another-dataframe-in-r), but there is another column at play.

I have two R dataframes:

df_1 has four columns. `Name1` has an associated type `Type1`. That is, A1 is of type T1, A4 is of type T3, etc. There is a final column of just names.

```
ID1     Name1     Type1     Name2
1       A1         T1        B1
2       A2         T2        B2
3       A3         T1        B3_a
4       A4         T3        B4_a
```

I have a second dataframe that has a list of all the names that could occur in `Name2`.

df_2:

```
NameBank     TypeBank
A1             T1
A2             T2
A3             T1
A4             T3
B1             T1
B2             T4
B3             T2
B4             T3
```

In df_1, `Name2` may have more characters than its associated value in `NameBank` in df_2.

I would like to find the `TypeBank` value in df_2 associated with `Name2` in df_1. That is, I would like a final data frame to look like this:

```
ID1     Name1     Type1     Name2     Type2
1       A1         T1        B1       T1
2       A2         T2        B2       T4
3       A3         T1        B3_a     T2
4       A4         T3        B4_a     T3
```

There are tens of thousands of entries in the first dataframe, and a few hundred entries in the second. How can I do this efficiently in R?

Comment: Do all values of `NameBank` always match the first 2 characters of the `Name2` value?

Comment: @rosscova Good question: no.

Comment: Are any extra characters always added to the end, and start with an underscore? If so, the answer by @missuse below should work.

Comment: Also a good question - my MWE was a bit too misleading from the looks of it, I apologize! The characters could be anything. The start will always contain a match: that is, instead of B3_a, I could have B3axyzlmnop, or B3ThisisaWord, or "B3 something else" with spaces.

Comment: Are the `NameBank` values always 2 characters long?

Comment: No, they are not. They are full words, and sometimes words with spaces.

Answer (score 2):

One approach using dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)

t1 %>%
  mutate(Name3 = sub("_[a-z]$", "", Name2)) %>%
  left_join(t2, by = c("Name3" = "NameBank")) %>%
  select(-Name3)

#output
  ID1 Name1 Type1 Name2 TypeBank
1   1    A1    T1    B1       T1
2   2    A2    T2    B2       T4
3   3    A3    T1  B3_a       T2
4   4    A4    T3  B4_a       T3
```

First we generate a new variable by removing `_` followed by any letter at the end of the string, and then join the two data frames by the new variable.

Depending on the relationship between `Name2` and `NameBank` some other string manipulation might be better suited.

data:

```
t1 <- read.table(text = "ID1     Name1     Type1     Name2
1       A1         T1        B1
2       A2         T2        B2
3       A3         T1        B3_a
4       A4         T3        B4_a", header = T)


t2 <- read.table(text = "NameBank     TypeBank
A1             T1
A2             T2
A3             T1
A4             T3
B1             T1
B2             T4
B3             T2
B4             T3", header = T)
```

EDIT: perhaps a better solution to your problem is to use `charmatch` which seeks matches for the elements of its first argument among those of its second.:

```
chrs <- charmatch(t2$NameBank, t1$Name2)
cbind(
  t1[chrs[!is.na(chrs)],],
  t2[which(!is.na(chrs)),]
)
#output
  ID1 Name1 Type1 Name2 NameBank TypeBank
1   1    A1    T1    B1       B1       T1
2   2    A2    T2    B2       B2       T4
3   3    A3    T1  B3_a       B3       T2
4   4    A4    T3  B4_a       B4       T3

chrs
[1] NA NA NA NA  1  2  3  4
```

so 5th element of `NameBank` matched the 1st element of `Name2` etc. End then just use that information to bind the two data frames appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're searching for matches at the start of strings, but you don't have any logical "regex-able" rules to go by, maybe go with a `for` loop.

We go through each value of `t2$NameBank`, find all rows in `t1` where the `NameBank` value matches the start (of the same length as the given `NameBank` value), and replace them with the corresponding `TypeBank` value.

```
t1$Type2 <- NA_character_
for( row in seq_len( nrow( t2 ) ) ) {
    t1$Type2[ substr( t1$Name2, 0, nchar( t2$NameBank[row] ) ) == t2$NameBank[row] ] <- t2$TypeBank[row]
}
```

Which gives

```
> t1
  ID1 Name1 Type1 Name2 Type2
1   1    A1    T1    B1    T1
2   2    A2    T2    B2    T4
3   3    A3    T1  B3_a    T2
4   4    A4    T3  B4_a    T3
```

It's a `for` loop, so it might be slow on a big dataset, but it seems like in your case it might be necessary.